# Convert different text user inputs to integers in a while-try loop in python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I´m still new to python and trying to convert a string user input to an integer.
My code looks like that:

```
var_input = input("Please input XX for a or YY for b:")

while True:
    
    try:
        
        if var_input == "XX":
            var_v = 1
            
        elif var_input == "YY":
            var_v = 0
        
        break;
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

I´m always ending up with var_v = 0

I´m sure there is a really simple way but i don´t get there.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: What input do you type?

Comment: i type two inputs like "GG" for "XX" or "PP" for "YY"

Comment: It is not ```break;```. It is ```break```

Comment: I can get `var_v = 1` when I enter `XX`.

Comment: What is `"GG"` or `"PP"`? You didn't mention that in your post.

Comment: ```ValueError``` won't be raised on entering wrong input

Comment: GG und PP are just example strings. I want to input two different strings and if the input is not one of these strings i want to get into the exception.

Comment: Wait, is the question about the value stored in `var_v` or about raising an exception?

Comment: I try it again to explain: There are two correct string user inputs. The first is for example "girl" and the second is "boy". Now if the user types "girl" in the input, the variable var_v should store the integer = 1 and if the user types "boy" the variable var_v should store the integer = 0. Everything else should end in the exception with a print("Invalid input")

Comment: Do you really need to have an exception? Could you instead just have the `print("Invalid input")`?

Comment: I need that if the input is not correct the user should have the option to do the input again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Not really because i have to check the if statements before the exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can change your code like this:

```py
while True:
    var_input = input("Please input XX for a or YY for b:")

    if var_input == "XX":
        var_v = 1
        
    elif var_input == "YY":
        var_v = 0
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        continue
    break

print(var_v)
print('Done')
```

I think this is what you want, but I don't see how it is different to the duplicate.